# Composition of two elements $|a|= p^m, |b|= p^n$ in abelian group, then order of composition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group with $a,b\in G$. If $|a|=p^m$ and $|b|=p^n$ for a prime $p$ with $n\ne m$, then for which $k$ below do we have $|ab|=p^k?$

Since $G$ is abelian, if we pick any integer, $k$,  $(ab)^k= a^kb^k$.

There is composition of two elements ($a,b$) of group.
The elements can be permutations in a proper subset of $S_n$, or simply members of $C_n.$

It can be useful to think as example: consider $\langle \mathbb{Z_{27}}, +\rangle.$ Some numbers worth considering are : $3, 6, 12, 15, 21, 24$ which all have an order of $9$, and $9, 18$ which have an order of $3$. Check what is the order of the sums of one number of the first set ($\{ 3, 6, 12, 15, 21, 24\},$) and one number of the second set ($\{9, 18\}$).
You pick a member $n$ of the first
set  and a member $m$ of the second set. Then let $p = m + n$. What can we say about the order of $p$ in the set of integers modulo $27$ under addition?

Comment: Can you help me to identify my mistake? Why my counter examples are wrong?

Comment: (This comment is so that @ArturoMagidin notices the comment above by Lost in Space.)

Comment: @LostinSpace I misread the OP's usual bad prose and had trouble verifying he was asking for the order. Thought what he wrote  only asked for values of $k$ that gave $(ab)^{p^k}=1$.

Comment: I think it is implied by Arturo's latest comment here that there is no mistake, @LostinSpace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the group $\Bbb{Z}_4×\Bbb{Z_8}$

Let $a=(1, 0) $ and $b=(0, 1) $ .

Then $|a|=\operatorname{lcm}(|1|, |0|) =\operatorname{lcm} (4, 1) =2^2$

$|b|=\operatorname{lcm}(|0|, |1|) =\operatorname{lcm} (1, 8) =2^3$

$ab=(1, 0) ×(0, 1) =(1+0, 0+1) =(1, 1) $

Then $|ab|=|(1, 1)=\operatorname{lcm}(|1|, |1|) =\operatorname{lcm} (4, 8) =2^3$

Here $m=2, n=3, k=3$

1. $k\neq |m-n|$
2. $k\neq mn$
3. $k\neq m+n$
4. $k\neq \min(m, n) $

In fact we will see $|ab|\mid p^{\max(m, n) }$

$|m-n|, mn, m+n, \min(m, n) $ may not divide $\max(m, n) $ . Hence $1, 2,3,5$ are false.

---

Fact $1)$ :

Since $G$ is abelian, there exists an element $c\in G$ such that $|c|=\operatorname{lcm }(p^m, p^n) =p^{\max(m, n) }$

Suppose $\max(m, n) =m$

$\begin{align}(ab) ^{p^{\max(m,n)}}&=a^{p^{\max(m,n)}}b^{p^{\max(m,n)}}\\&=a^{p^m} b ^{dp^n}\quad[\text{$p^n\mid p^m$ $\space ,p^m=dp^n$}]\\&=e(b^{p^n})^d\\&=e \end{align}$

Hence $|ab|\mid p^{\max(m, n) }$

---

Fact $2) $ : Consider $\langle a\rangle$  and $\langle b\rangle$  . Then $|\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle|\mid \gcd(p^m,p^n)=p^{\min(m,n)}$

Case $1$ : $\min(m, n) =1$

$|\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle|=1$

Then $|ab|=\operatorname{lcm}(p^m, p^n) =p^{\max(m, n) }$

Case $2$: $\min(m, n) =p^r$ for some $0<r|\min(m, n) $

If $|\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle|=p^r$

Either case $2$ can be proved or can be used to produce a counter example.

Note: It's not a complete proof. I will follow this proof to update latter.

Comment: What is the meaning of $|a|=\operatorname{lcm}(|1|, |0|) =\operatorname{lcm} (4, 1) =2^2.$ Tried: Order of element $a$ is given by LCM of orders of two elements,$1,0.$ But, couldn't understand.

Comment: Yes. $|1|$ in $Z_4$ is $4 $ and $|0|$ in $Z_8$  is $1$

Comment: Why did you accept the answer when you didn't understand it, @jiten?

Comment: @Shaun Because at that time looked not at it thoroughly, and his earlier answers are great.

Comment: So, LCM of order of two elements gives the pair's order. Please tell if it has some specific name too.

Comment: Check order of an element in a direct product group.